# Transfer Multiple Textbox value into Pie Chart slices(Percentage)

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

Thanks for the help on my past question. i think this would the last.
Here is my latest code on my question

http://jsfiddle.net/3es9gzxy/6/

in there i have 5 categories with textboxes.

My goal is like this

Texbox 1  Value: 20
Texbox 2  Value: 20
Texbox 3  Value: 20
Texbox 4  Value: 22
Texbox 5  Value: 18

The value of the chart will be same in my textbox but its not working how can i achieve this? You can try and edit it. TY

here is the part of my code

```
(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: 1,//null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Crimes for this Year'
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                        style: {
                            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Browser share',
                data: [
                    ['Arson',   0],
                    ['Homicide',       0],
                    ['Physical Injuries',   0],
                    ['Carnapping',       0],
                    ['Ethical Law Violation',       0]

                                ]
            }]
        });
    });
                     function pie (){                 
    $('#chart').on('click', function() {

    var value = Number($('#arson').val());
    var value = Number($('#homicde').val());
    var value = Number($('#physicalinjuries').val());
    var value = Number($('#carnapping').val());
    var value = Number($('#elv').val());

       var myChart = $('#container').highcharts();

       myChart.series[0].data[0].update(value); 
     myChart.series[0].data[1].update(value); 
         myChart.series[0].data[2].update(value); 
     myChart.series[0].data[3].update(value); 
         myChart.series[0].data[4].update(value); 

    });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing quite an obvious mistake : each time you read a value you erase the previous one. What's more you redefine many times value as a new var... You might want to "use strict"; to have an exception thrown on such mistake.
You also misspelled 'homicide' in 'homicde', which prevented the computation.
And the thing would work only after a first click, so i changed the fiddle to start on dom ready, and hooked the click handler directly.
After that, you can see you have very similar code : time to make a function !!

http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/3es9gzxy/8/

```
$('#chart').on('click', function () {

    var myChart = $('#container').highcharts();

    var wrongValue = false;

    function setValue(type, slot) {
        var value = Number($('#' + type).val());
        if (isNaN(value) || value === undefined) {
            wrongValue = true;
            value = 0;
        }
        myChart.series[0].data[slot].update(value);
    }

    setValue('arson', 0);
    setValue('homicide', 1);
    setValue('physicalinjuries', 2);
    setValue('carnapping', 3);
    setValue('elv', 4);

    if (wrongValue) {
        // warn the user.
    }

});
```

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, i see now i went right to the point... :-) But my bet is you'll understand it all when reading the code. Otherwise do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: So happy with that really so so much. It works very perfect. I notice if the value of 5 textboxes is greather that 100 it will be back into 100% for me its ok. Math Basics :D

Comment: yes highcharts seems not to consider you're providing a percentage, but rather a value, (maybe that's something you can change somehow with this API, donno, i would handle that by myself anyway since i have to warn the user that all figures do not sum-up to 100%... or even tolerate some small error, ...., depends on your goal/inputs/... ).

Comment: The reason why i ask this question is because i will use the command select(count) from table in my database and transfer it in those textboxes then update the charts. My friend told me that my select command will give me an output of a whole number then he also told that i need to compute it before it has to be turn as percentage then transfer that in the chart. something like that, what can you say about this?

Comment: Since highCharts can do the maths, let him do i'd say : use genuine figures, and you'll later have the chance to display relative AND/OR absolute figures on your charts.

Comment: Thanks for the idea Sir, ahhm sir can i ask some question? Would you like to see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27584116/how-to-use-database-data-to-call-an-image-and-use-it-as-leaflet-marker-image?noredirect=1#comment43592905_27584116

Comment: Wow that's awesome sir but this code doesn't interrogate with the user i will pass the value from my database in the textbox then update the highcharts but that was an awesome one :D